# How to make a streaks in python (count if something is right then add 1 to a variable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, counting

I'm testing stuff with pythong (I'm really mediocre and still learning); I made a game thing and i want to count how many times wins/guesses. I've tried some ways that define a function but the variable must be called before the function so it resets; again I'm really bad so I'd appreciate if someone can write me an example/explanation. PS: I'm new to stack overflow if  you can't tell so apologies if didnt use a specific format or something :D

Comment: Hey there. So does your game run as a loop? If it does, you can use something like a `count` variable, which can increase at each iteration of the loop if a condition is true.

Comment: Yea it does, but I cant just do count += 1; i'd have to mention count before right?

Comment: If you define count **before** you begin your loop, and then increment it in your loop (or not), that should work

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking too much, but how do i make it go to the start of the loop

Comment: Okay, I'll make this into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count wins, a good way to do this is with a for loop. These are sections of code with repeat a certain number of times. You can put your main game structure in a function, which is completed at each iteration of the loop. So let's say your actual game is a function called `main_game()`:

```py
def main_game():
    # all your game code can go here
    if won: # you can change this to reflect your own code
        return True # the return statement passes a value back to the place that called it
    else:
        return False
```

A side note: if you don't understand basic python constructs like `return` or `def`, take a look at the [python docs](https://docs.python.org).

We can then loop this function round. The `range()` here takes an argument which represents the number of times this should be carried out, so in this case 10 times.

```py
wins = 0
for i in range(10): # this a for loop. "i" represents the iteration of the loop.
    result = main_game() # this calls the function
    if result == True: # in other words, if they've scored
         wins = wins+1 # add one to the wins total
```

The expression `result = main_game()` basically assigns whatever `main_game()` returns to a variable called `result`. That's why we use `return True` rather than `print(True)` in our `main_game` function, because it sends that value back to `result`.

Then it checks to see if the user won, and if so, increments their win total before iterating. Notice there are no `elif` or `else` statements, because if `result` is anything other than `True`, we don't have to do anything with the win total.

This is a basic skeleton for how you can use a counter which goes up based on a condition to do with your game, and requires some expansion, but should give you a few pointers.

Comment: Ohhh I get it now, i was missing defining the whole game in a function. Thank you so much for the help! Enjoy the rest of you day

Comment: @Sadacato ^ see above; forgot to @ you